# pipeline-aws-plugin of cfnUpdate trows WaiterUnrecoverableException

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, aws-cloudformation

When trying to run **cfnUpdate** of [pipeline-aws-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-aws-plugin) I get WaiterUnrecoverableException, but when creating the stack by the Amazon console it is created without problem

#### Details:

Version Pipeline: AWS Steps 1.27

I'm trying to execute:

```
cfnUpdate(stack:"${stack}", url:"${urlTemplate}", params: 'roleName':"${roleName}",'bucket':"${bucket}",'pathS3':"${pathS3}",'handler':"${handler}"],timeoutInMinutes:10)
```

**Where**

- `${stack}` is a number of the stack
- `${urlTemplate}` is a link to a template saved at S3

And throws in the Jenkins log:

> com.amazonaws.waiters.WaiterUnrecoverableException: Resource never entered the desired state as it failed.
>       at com.amazonaws.waiters.WaiterExecution.pollResource(WaiterExecution.java:78)
>       at com.amazonaws.waiters.WaiterImpl.run(WaiterImpl.java:88)
>       at com.amazonaws.waiters.WaiterImpl$1.call(WaiterImpl.java:110)
>       at com.amazonaws.waiters.WaiterImpl$1.call(WaiterImpl.java:106)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>       Caused: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException
>       at org.apache.http.concurrent.BasicFuture.getResult(BasicFuture.java:71)
>       at org.apache.http.concurrent.BasicFuture.get(BasicFuture.java:84)
>       at de.taimos.pipeline.aws.cloudformation.EventPrinter.waitAndPrintEvents(EventPrinter.java:135)
>       at de.taimos.pipeline.aws.cloudformation.EventPrinter.waitAndPrintStackEvents(EventPrinter.java:92)
>       at de.taimos.pipeline.aws.cloudformation.CloudFormationStack.create(CloudFormationStack.java:119)
>       at de.taimos.pipeline.aws.cloudformation.CFNUpdateStep$Execution.whenStackMissing(CFNUpdateStep.java:125)
>       at de.taimos.pipeline.aws.cloudformation.AbstractCFNCreateStep$Execution$1.run(AbstractCFNCreateStep.java:137)

As a reference, my template is similar to:

[Cloudformation Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cs9uA.png)

Maybe someone can help me with this or recommend me some adjustment?

regards

Answer (score 0):

You are closing the "params" array, but you are not opening it. Try this:

`cfnUpdate(stack:"${stack}", url:"${urlTemplate}", params: ['roleName':"${roleName}",'bucket':"${bucket}",'pathS3':"${pathS3}",'handler':"${handler}"],timeoutInMinutes:10)`